# How to write python in vs code on ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

I downloaded the Microsoft's Python extension for vs code. When i press "Run Build Task" it says "Select a build task to run" and "No build task to run found. Configure Build Task" also in the right bottom corner, a little window opened which says "Linter pylint is not installed" and when i click "Install", it says "There is no Pip installer available in the selected environment". I searched youtube and saw people write python in vs code on Windows.They opened launch.json and paste the location where python is installed. I also tried that but it didn't work. So what you recommend in order to writing a working "Hello World!" code?

Comment: The official documentation should do the job: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python.

It worked pretty well for me.

Comment: @herve there is nothing for my problem. are you an ubuntu user?

Comment: You don't have to install Pylint to have the extension work (Ubuntu doesn't include pip by default and so you need to install that; don't remember the name of the package off the top of my head). And to execute a file you can follow the answer that @jmh provided.

Comment: @BrettCannon so how can i disable the warning for install Pylint?

Comment: @ErhanYümer you can set `"python.linting.pylintEnabled": false` or you can click the "Don't show again" button on that notification.

Comment: I am a part-time ubuntu user and I installed a brand new vscode this morning. I got the same error until I selected the python interpreter as depicted in the installation steps of the extension `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `P` and `"Python: Select interpreter"`. Mine is a conda install. Also, you can click on the error message which redirects you to the right documentation page. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

if you place your cursor in the editor window and right-click. One of the options towards the bottom is: Run python file in terminal.

You can also load the extension Code Runner and it has other options to run the code. Once you load Code Runner go to the extension icon on the left of the editor window and the Code Runner shows up in the VScode window and you can scroll thru it to see how to use this extension.